# Sub-menu not visible on mouseover

Tags: css, web, menu

I was request to use the Lit Theme from MDNW, on the dark skin the sub-menu doesn't even appear visible when mousing over the menu (but the light theme it does). How would I go about fixing this?

I had seen that someone suggested on another question pertaining to a sub-menu not showing on their own project by applying a relative position (position:relative) to the super-containers and descending z-index to each super-container as you go down the page.

This theme is no longer supported by the developer, but still being sold.

Demo: http://lit-dark.mdnw.net/

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In skin-dark.css

```
    /*MAIN BG*/
body, 
.container{ 
    background: #000;
    position: relative;
    /*z-index: 1;*/
}
```

Remove the z-index